# Image is send in request.POST but cleaned in form.cleaned_data

Tags: django

I've a Profile form that accepts an Image to be used to display User's Profile Pic.

I don't have problems submitting the form, but when accessing the admin panel I can see that the file has not been saved.

[image]

Even thought, It is send in request.POST:

> 'photo': ['es_usted_inteligente.jpg']}>

```
SIGNUP REQUEST POST:  <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['SXoar0hPxsKCcMgFG1lJ5XoxjCzbEEqa9x5livVw4M0m9ZB25SGKmL3IUogJnxHz'], 'first_name': ['a'], 'last_name': ['gonzales']
, 'username': ['agonzales'], 'dni': ['744484848'], 'phone_number': ['89898989'], 'birthdate_month': ['1'], 'birthdate_day': ['1'], 'birthdate_year': ['1980'], 'email': ['agon
zales@gmail.com'], 'password1': ['caballo123'], 'password2': ['caballo123'], 'shipping_address1': ['Urb. La Merced Mz.G Lot.32'], 'address_reference': ['Tienda Roja'], 'shipp
ing_department': ['San Martín'], 'shipping_province': ['El Dorado'], 'shipping_district': ['Shatoja'], 'photo': ['es_usted_inteligente.jpg']}>
```

**profile_form.cleaned_data:**

> 'photo': None}

```
  profile_form.cleaned_data: {'dni': '48494949', 'phone_number': '9898989', 'birthdate': datetime.date(1980, 1, 1), 'shipping_address1': 'Urb. La Merced Mz.G Lot.32', 'address
_reference': 'Tienda Roja', 'shipping_department': 'Lambayeque', 'shipping_province': 'Chiclayo', 'shipping_district': 'Saña', 'photo': None}
```

View:

```
@transaction.atomic
def signupView(request):
    peru = Peru.objects.all()
    department_list = set()
    province_list = set()
    district_list = set()
    for p in peru:
        department_list.add(p.departamento)
    department_list = list(department_list)
    # print("Department List: ", department_list)
    if len(department_list):
        province_list = set(Peru.objects.filter(departamento=department_list[0]).values_list("provincia", flat=True))
        # print("Provice List: ", province_list)
        province_list = list(province_list)
        # print("dfsfs", province_list)
    else:
        province_list = set()
    if len(province_list):
        district_list = set(
            Peru.objects.filter(departamento=department_list[0], provincia=province_list[0]).values_list("distrito",
                                                                                                         flat=True))
        # print("district List: ", district_list)
    else:
        district_list = set()

    if request.method == 'POST':


        #####

        peru = Peru.objects.all()
        department_list = set()
        province_list = set()
        district_list = set()
        for p in peru:
            department_list.add(p.departamento)
        department_list = list(department_list)

        if len(department_list):
            province_list = set(
                Peru.objects.filter(departamento__in=department_list).values_list("provincia", flat=True))

            province_list = list(province_list)

        else:
            province_list = set()
        if len(province_list):
            district_list = set(
                Peru.objects.filter(departamento__in=department_list, provincia__in=province_list).values_list(
                    "distrito",
                    flat=True))

        else:
            district_list = set()

        #####

        user_form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list, request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            username = user_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            signup_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            customer_group = Group.objects.get(name='Clientes')
            customer_group.user_set.add(signup_user)
            raw_password = user_form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user.refresh_from_db()  # This will load the Profile created by the Signal

            profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list, request.POST,
                                       instance=user.profile)  # Reload the profile form with the profile instance
            profile_form.full_clean()  # Manually clean the form this time. It is implicitly called by "is_valid()" method
            profile_form.save()  # Gracefully save the form

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)

            return redirect('carrito_de_compras:cart_detail')

        else:
            print(user_form.errors)
            print(profile_form.errors)

    else:

        user_form = SignUpForm()

        profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list)


    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

**models.py:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    dni = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    shipping_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    address_reference = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    shipping_department = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    shipping_province = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    shipping_district = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', default='profile_pics/default_profile_pic_white.png')


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.first_name) + "'s profile"
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    MONTHS = {
        1:'ene', 2:'feb', 3:'mar', 4:'abr',
        5:'may', 6:'jun', 7:'jul', 8:'ago',
        9:'set', 10:'oct', 11:'nov', 12:'dic'
    }

    def __init__(self, district_list, province_list, department_list, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['shipping_district'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Distrito', choices=tuple([(name, name) for name in district_list]))
        self.fields['shipping_province'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Provincia', choices=tuple([(name, name) for name in province_list]))
        self.fields['shipping_department'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Departamento', choices=tuple([(name, name) for name in department_list]))


    dni = forms.CharField(label='DNI', max_length=100, required=True)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(label='Celular')
    birthdate = forms.DateField(label='Fecha de nacimiento', widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(1980, 2012), months=MONTHS))
    shipping_address1 = forms.CharField(label='Dirección de envío', max_length=100, required=True)
    address_reference = forms.CharField(label='Referencia', max_length=100, required=False)
    photo = forms.ImageField(label='Foto de perfil', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('dni', 'phone_number', 'birthdate', 'shipping_address1',
                  'address_reference', 'shipping_department', 'shipping_province', 'shipping_district', 'photo')
```

**UPDATE 1**:

After adding request.FILES to :

> ```
>     user_form = SignUpForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
>     profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list, request.POST, request.FILES)
> ```

I cannot find the attribute photo in `request.POST`:

```
SIGNUP REQUEST POST:  <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['8xcGwGg7z86OclANaEYwdB49u5hrCjOy7gFKSgoqmhxS0CmzeBIUgnYUdRyTnzqJ'], 'first_name': ['g'], 'last_name': ['gonzales']
, 'username': ['ggonzales'], 'dni': ['45484545'], 'phone_number': ['968484848'], 'birthdate_month': ['1'], 'birthdate_day': ['1'], 'birthdate_year': ['1980'], 'email': ['ggon
zales@gmail.com'], 'password1': ['caballo123'], 'password2': ['caballo123'], 'shipping_address1': ['Urb. La Merced Mz.G Lot.32'], 'address_reference': ['Tienda Roja'], 'shipp
ing_department': ['Huancavelica'], 'shipping_province': ['Castrovirreyna'], 'shipping_district': ['Castrovirreyna']}>
```

But now, profile_form.cleaned_data has at least the `deault pic` instead of `None` :

```
Profile Cleaned Data:  {'dni': '45484545', 'phone_number': '968484848', 'birthdate': datetime.date(1980, 1, 1), 'shipping_address1': 'Urb. La Merced Mz.G Lot.32', 'address_re
ference': 'Tienda Roja', 'shipping_department': 'Huancavelica', 'shipping_province': 'Castrovirreyna', 'shipping_district': 'Castrovirreyna', 'photo': <ImageFieldFile: profil
e_pics/default_profile_pic_white.png>}
```

**HTML for form:**

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=".">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ user_form.first_name.label_tag }}</th>
                                <td>
                                    {{ user_form.first_name.errors }}
                                    {{ user_form.first_name }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ user_form.last_name.label_tag }}</th>
                                <td>
                                    {{ user_form.last_name.errors }}
                                    {{ user_form.last_name }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ user_form.username.label_tag }}</th>
                                <td>
                                    {{ user_form.username.errors }}
                                    {{ user_form.username }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ profile_form.dni.label_tag }}</th>
                                <td>{{ profile_form.dni }}<i data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
                                                             style="margin-left: 5px"
                                                             class="far fa-question-circle"></i></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ profile_form.phone_number.label_tag }}</th>
                                <td>{{ profile_form.phone_number }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ profile_form.birthdate.label_tag }}</th>
                                <td>{{ profile_form.birthdate }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ user_form.email.label_tag }}</th>
                                <td>{{ user_form.email }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="errorlist">{{ user_form.password2.errors.0 }}</span>
                                    <span class="errorlist">{{ user_form.password2.errors.1 }}</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ user_form.password1.label_tag }}</th>
                                <td>
                                    {{ user_form.password1.errors }}
                                    {{ user_form.password1 }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ user_form.password2.label_tag }}</th>
                                <td>
                                    {{ user_form.password2 }}

                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

                </div>


                <div class="col-md-6">

                    <table>

                        <tr>
                            <th>{{ profile_form.shipping_address1.label_tag }}</th>
                            <td>
                                {{ profile_form.shipping_address1.errors }}
                                {{ profile_form.shipping_address1 }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{ profile_form.address_reference.label_tag }}</th>
                            <td>
                                {{ profile_form.address_reference.errors }}
                                {{ profile_form.address_reference }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{ profile_form.shipping_department.label_tag }}</th>
                            <td>
                                {{ profile_form.shipping_department.errors }}
                                {{ profile_form.shipping_department }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{ profile_form.shipping_province.label_tag }}</th>
                            <td>
                                {{ profile_form.shipping_province.errors }}
                                {{ profile_form.shipping_province }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{ profile_form.shipping_district.label_tag }}</th>
                            <td>
                                {{ profile_form.shipping_district.errors }}
                                {{ profile_form.shipping_district }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{ profile_form.photo.label_tag }}</th>
                            <td>
                                {{ profile_form.photo.errors }}
                                {{ profile_form.photo }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <p></p>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Registrarse</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                    </table>

                </div>

                </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pick up files so you need `user_form = SignUpForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`.

Also, make sure you've got `enctype="multipart/form-data"` within your form declaration in the hmtl.  Something like `<form id="projectForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">`